# Using boost's shared memory

Tags: windows, visual-c++, boost

I would like to use Boost's shared memory services to do the following. I have been begun studying the documentation but as a aid to that was hoping someone could provide an example that is close to what I want to do.

Here it is:

Process A will write messages to a buffer area. It will also maintain a map, mapping message ID to information regarding the start location and size of the message in the buffer. Some locking mechanism, possibly a scoped lock, will control access to the map and buffer area.

Process B will read these messages based upon message ID.

Thanks in advance for any constructive suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Interprocess - message queue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.message_queue) documentation?

It doesn't do exactly what you're asking for, as far as making each message have an ID and such, but you don't go into detail as to why that is necessary.  Since there's only two processes, will it work to simply copy the data over to process B?